# a way to transfer column names on values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this pandas dataframe.
[image]

Is there a way that I could transfer (or melt??) the column names on the `1` and make it more categorical like:

```
              style    major  main_ingredient
chu            1.0      0.0    red meat fish
toro           1.0      0.0    red meat fish
negi_toro      1.0      0.0    red meat fish
maguro         1.0      0.0    red meat fish
tarabagani     1.0      0.0    shrimp or crab
amaebi         1.0      0.0    shrimp or crab
negi_toro_maki 0.0      0.0    red meat fish
ebi            1.0      1.0    shrimp or crab
kurumaebi      1.0      0.0    shrimp or crab
kani           1.0      0.0    shrimp or crab
```

Answer (score 0):

Melt should work. However it will leave you with another column with all the values from columns that are melted:

```
pd.melt(df, id_vars=['style', 'major'], var_name='main_ingriedient', value_name='value', ignore_index=False)
```